# Troubleshooting or Reconfiguring control Key on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout, macbook-pro

I have a late 2012 Macbook Pro with a non-functioning command key.  Pressing the key does not register any keyboard event in Atom, terminal or other program, and as I try to become more familiar with the Terminal, its becoming increasingly frustrating.  I am interested in why the key does not work, but have no idea where to even begin troubleshooting the thing.  In all honesty, I don't know when it stopped working and the laptop has seen a lot of wear, been rebuilt, and had some major mods (which I will detail below).  But I'm not afraid of trying to actually fix the problem . . . I just don't know where to start.  Physically there's no signs of damage anywhere at or around the key.

I suspect that it may be easier and more fruitful to simply remap a different key to register as the control key, and I would be 100% happy and satisfied with this solution, although ideally I wouldn't have to install some kind of 3rd party software to do so.  I looked through previously asked questions and found: [MacBook Pro Keyboard - How to Swap / Remap Keys?](http://MacBook%20Pro%20Keyboard%20-%20How%20to%20Swap%20/%20Remap%20Keys?) and I am aware of [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net) Worst case scenario, I can go that route, but it's not my preference. I'm hoping there's a way to go "under the hood" and just make OS X recognize a different key (say the left option key) as Control.

What's been done to it:

Logicboard/memory/CPU replaced after spilling beer through the I/O ports. :(  It was half the cost to roll-back to replacement parts from late 2011 model and downgrade from an i7 to an i5, and physically it was a perfect swap, so that's what I did.

Replaced stock HD with a Sandisk SSD.

Initially had a bootcamp partition with Windows 10.  Removed after realizing that even a on a macbook, Windows still has all the things I dislike about it.

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Another note: if you use Doublecommand and love it, have no problems with it, want to sing its name from a rooftop, then speak up.  I've had so many annoying to awful experiences with third party solutions to little problems that I'm reluctant to go that route, but I don't have anything specific against doublecommand other than it is 3rd party.

Comment: You can remap some modifier keys in System Preferences > Keyboards. I remap CapsLock on every machine I own. Just a side note, no 3rd party software necessary. The caveat is it is a per-keyboard setting (so if you have an external keyboard too, you'd need to apply it there too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can just change it at System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys...**

Choose the keyboard at the top (in your case the default Apple one) and than you can change the Command key to Capslock, Control, Option, or you can fully disable it if you want.

[image: Settings panel]

Hope it helps, and +1 for deleting Windows :D